# How to calculate the right size for error bars

Tags: statistics

I am estimating $P(A|B)$ by random sampling. I do $N$ samples and event "$A$ and $B$" occurs $x$ times and event $B$ occurs $y$ times so my estimate of  $P(A|B)$ is $x/y$.

> I would like to plot this estimate with suitable error bars.  How
>   large should these be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you estimate a priori about the probability, but the rule of thumb is that any statistical measurement of $x$ has an error of about $\pm\sqrt x$ (or a relative error of $\approx\frac1{\sqrt x}$). With that simple rule, your error bars should go from $\frac{x-\sqrt x}{y+\sqrt y}$ up to $\frac{x+\sqrt x}{y-\sqrt y}$. In other words, the relative error is $\approx \frac1{\sqrt x}+\frac1{\sqrt y}$.

This is not fully justified for several reasons, but probably the best bet one can get without further assumptions.

Comment: Thanks so I am dividing x/y too which presumably makes things worse.  My problem is that the true probability is small but I do have a rough estimate for it. Let's say the true probability is $p$.

Comment: What further assumptions would help?

Answer (score 0):

A standard way to construct a confidence interval for a probability like $\mathrm{P}(B)=p$ is to use the binomial distribution.  That is, you perform $n$ trials and let $Y\sim\mathrm{Binomial}(n,p)$.  Then, for a large enough sample size, you can approximate with the Normal distribution.  Defining $\hat{p}=Y/n$,
$$
  \mathrm{P}\left( 
     \left\lvert \hat{p}-p  \right\rvert \le
     z_\alpha\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}} 
  \right) \approx \alpha
$$
where you would choose $z_\alpha$ to get the coverage you desire.  For example, $z_\alpha=1.96$ results in the standard 95% confidence interval.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval for more details and other methods.

The problem you have stated is slightly trickier.  You could construct confidence intervals for $\mathrm{P}(A\cap B)$ and $\mathrm{P}(B)$ separately.  However, you do **not** want to divide them, because the resulting "interval" will no longer be at the $\alpha$-level (i.e. no longer contain the true $p$ for $\alpha$% of the time ).  One possibility is to compute your $x$ and $y$ as stated and then use the normal approximation to the binomial confidence interval with $n=y$ and $\hat{p}=x/y$.  Explicitly, you would get
$$
  \frac{x}{y} \pm z_\alpha \frac{1}{y}{\sqrt{x(y-x)}}.
$$
You may also want to try some of the other (generally more complicated) formulae from the Wikipedia page.  Depending on your sample size, or in particular, the measure of set $B$, another method may provide more accurate results.